# Firestore query after previous queries last document?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I first do a query and get the first 30 "Most Liked" posts and send that to the client, along with the last document of that query.

Next I (try to) query the next 30 documents when the client loads more. I send the last document back and try to query off that, but every attempt either fails or loads the same posts as before.

```
exports.loadTrendingPosts = functions.https.onCall(async(data, context) => {
   var startData = data.startAt; //either null(first load) or previous last document
   var currentTime = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now();
   var lastDocument;
   var monthYearCompare = '202001';

   if(startData !== null && startData !== undefined){

    //produces the error "Cannot read property 'firestore' of undefined"
    //startData = new admin.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot(data.startData);

    //produces the error "Cannot read property 'firestore' of undefined"
    //startData = new admin.firestore.DocumentSnapshot(data.startData);

    var postSnap = await db.collection('posts')
        .where('nextTwelveMonths', 'array-contains', monthYearCompare)
        .orderBy('likes', 'desc')
        .startAfter(startData)
        .limit(30)
        .get();
   }
   else{ //initial load
      postSnap = await db.collection('posts').where('nextTwelveMonths', 'array-contains', monthYearCompare).orderBy('likes', 'desc').limit(30).get();
      lastDocument = postSnap.docs[postSnap.docs.length - 1]

   }
   
  return [postsSnap, lastDocument];
});
```

`startData` comes back to the function as JSON/maps.
Things I've tried:

-If I try to query starting after `startData` without any changes, I get no errors, but I get the same 30 posts as the initial query.

-If without changes I try to use `startData.data().likes` I get the error `startData.data is not a function`

-If I try to convert the JSON/maps to a `DocumentSnapshot` or `QueryDocumentSnapshot` to enable me to use `.data()` I get the error `Cannot read property 'firestore' of undefined`.

I'm not able to add a `where('likes', '<', lastMinLikes)` due to lots of the posts having the same amount of likes.

Any ideas on how I can load the next 30 documents in this situation?

Edit: here is what startData looks like when sending back the document from the client side (via Flutter):
(When I `startAt` using this, I get the same initial 30 documents ~ it makes no difference).

Edit: came up with a solution, see answer below.

```
{_createTime: {_nanoseconds: 412572000, _seconds: 1613004211}, _fieldsProto: {fileName: {stringValue: image_picker_CDEC8665-93ED-4453-A021-2E2F2B7C86F7-3920-000002602CF620C2.jpg, valueType: stringValue}, comments: {valueType: arrayValue, arrayValue: {values: []}}, nextTwentyFour: {valueType: arrayValue, arrayValue: {values: [{stringValue: 2021011100, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 2021011101, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 2021011102, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 2021011103, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 2021011104, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 2021011105, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 2021011106, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 2021011107, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 2021011108, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 2021011109, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 2021011110, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 2021011111, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 2021011112, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 2021011113, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 2021011114, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 2021011115, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 2021011116, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 2021011117, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 2021011118, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 2021011119, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 2021011120, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 2021011121, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 2021011122, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 2021011123, valueType: stringValue}]}}, nextTwelveMonths: {valueType: arrayValue, arrayValue: {values: [{stringValue: 202102, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 202103, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 202104, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 202105, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 202106, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 202107, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 202108, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 202109, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 202110, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 202111, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 202200, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 202201, valueType: stringValue}]}}, campaignID: {stringValue: kLgdsaYbuqdf1w5UXRp9, valueType: stringValue}, dealID: {stringValue: 0b8ImRRtnKcsGWrTJ5rI, valueType: stringValue}, nextThirtyOneDays: {valueType: arrayValue, arrayValue: {values: [{stringValue: 20210111, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 20210112, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 20210113, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 20210114, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 20210115, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 20210116, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 20210117, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 20210118, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 20210119, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 20210120, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 20210121, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 20210122, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 20210123, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 20210124, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 20210125, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 20210126, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 20210127, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 20210128, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 20210201, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 20210202, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 20210203, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 20210204, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 20210205, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 20210206, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 20210207, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 20210208, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 20210209, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 20210210, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 20210211, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 20210212, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 20210213, valueType: stringValue}]}}, caption: {stringValue: Nails all done , valueType: stringValue}, userCreatorsName: {stringValue: John Onewick, valueType: stringValue}, commentCount: {valueType: integerValue, integerValue: 0}, usersCreatorsID: {stringValue: xaLbvMoFlzQgU0w1UeZqvWiVHy92, valueType: stringValue}, size: {valueType: integerValue, integerValue: 1}, usersName: {stringValue: Four Loko, valueType: stringValue}, usersID: {stringValue: C1oiRCuj6OQOF0aXgaAlzSKOe2y2, valueType: stringValue}, campaignName: {stringValue: Epc Gamer Moments, valueType: stringValue}, nextSevenDays: {valueType: arrayValue, arrayValue: {values: [{stringValue: 20210111, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 20210112, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 20210113, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 20210114, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 20210115, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 20210116, valueType: stringValue}, {stringValue: 20210117, valueType: stringValue}]}}, fileType: {valueType: integerValue, integerValue: 0}, timestamp: {timestampValue: {seconds: 1613004211, nanos: 278000000}, valueType: timestampValue}, likes: {valueType: integerValue, integerValue: 0}}, _ref: {_firestore: {_clientPool: {terminateDeferred: {resolve: {}, reject: {}, promise: {}}, clientFactory: {}, clientDestructor: {}, maxIdleClients: 1, concurrentOperationLimit: 100, activeClients: {}, failedClients: {}, terminated: false}, _settings: {firebaseVersion: 9.4.2, libName: gccl, projectId: removeForStackOF-XXX, libVersion: 4.8.1 fire/9.4.2}, _settingsFrozen: true, _serializer: {allowUndefined: false, createReference: {}, createInteger: {}}, bulkWritersCount: 0, registeredListenersCount: 0, _backoffSettings: {backoffFactor: 1.3, maxDelayMs: 60000, initialDelayMs: 100}, _projectId: removeForStackOF-XXX}, _converter: {toFirestore: {}, fromFirestore: {}}, _path: {databaseId: (default), projectId: removeForStackOF-XXX, segments: [posts, 0b8ImRRtnKcsGWrTJ5rI]}}, _serializer: {allowUndefined: false, createReference: {}, createInteger: {}}, _readTime: {_nanoseconds: 522978000, _seconds: 1613095062}, _updateTime: {_nanoseconds: 412572000, _seconds: 1613004211}}
```

Comment: Can you add what `startData` is containing? Also the schema of a document. Fields of different types are ordered.

Comment: @ChrisWilcox added. It contains all document fields + additional metadata. (The document contains lot's of date strings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the data coming in from `startData` which is being used for `startAfter` is not well formed. I created a sample collection '0' With the following entities.

```
ID    n
--------
a     3
b     1
b2    1
c     2
```

The below code demonstrates if start after 'b' is specified the result is as expected.

```
const Firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const db = new Firestore()

let query = db.collection('0');

db.collection('0').doc('b').get().then(b => {

    query.orderBy('n').startAfter(b).get().then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(document => {
            console.log(document.id + " " + document.get('n'));
        });
    });

});
```

This returns

```
b2 1
c 2
a 3
```

If you don't have access to the complete object, you can order by id in addition to likes in your case, and then start after the id and the likes.

for example:

```
const lastRef = db.collection('0').doc('b');
const lastValue = "1"
query.orderBy('n').orderBy(Firestore.FieldPath.documentId()).startAfter(lastValue, lastRef).get().then(snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach(document => {
        console.log(document.id + " " + document.get('n'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes I believe the same thing (it got converted to JSON), do you know if I could turn the JSON doc back into a valid document to use for the query?  `startData = new admin.firestore.DocumentSnapshot(data.startData)` results in `Cannot read property 'firestore' of undefined` (although in my code I use a firestore timestamp, so I don't know what is undefined).

Comment: What does that map look like though? Can you share an example?

If you provide lastDocument to this it should work as in my post.

Answer (score 1):

Sending the last document from a cloud function to Flutter and back made it unusable in a `startAt` query for unknown reasons. (Maybe because it can't be declared as a `DocumentSnapshot`).

What I did instead is send only the last documents ID to Flutter, then back to the backend when loading more. When loading extra data I snapshot that document ID, and `startAt` that snapshot and it works as intended.

This costs 1 extra document snapshot, but there is less data being sent between the client and the backend, and most importantly it works.

Ex:

```
exports.loadTrendingPosts = functions.https.onCall(async(data, context) => {
   var startData = data.startAt; //either null(first load) or previous last documents ID
   var currentTime = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now();
   var lastDocument;
   var monthYearCompare = '202001';

   if(startData !== null && startData !== undefined){
    var lastDocSnap = await db.collection('posts').doc(startData).get(); //snapshot the last document from it's ID
    postSnap = await db.collection('posts')
        .where('nextTwelveMonths', 'array-contains', monthYearCompare)
        .orderBy('likes', 'desc')
        .startAfter(lastDocSnap)
        .limit(30)
        .get();
   }
   else{ //initial load
      postSnap = await db.collection('posts').where('nextTwelveMonths', 'array-contains', monthYearCompare).orderBy('likes', 'desc').limit(30).get();
      lastDocument = (postSnap.docs[postSnap.docs.length - 1]).id; //get the ID instead of the document

   }
   
  return [postsSnap, lastDocument];
});
```

Comment: Happy you were able to unblock. I considered this but was avoiding recommending making an additional request.

FYI, I filed a question/issue against our Node.js library. I don't see a reason rehydrating an object from JSON doesn't work, but perhaps one of the engineers more familiar can provide further details. https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/issues/1424

Comment: I expanded my answer to show how to do this with a shallow reference.